# How add gesture into the tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

everyone!

I am trying to add gesture to a UIImageView into the TableViewCell.
When click on the ImageView - the color changes.

```
class StocksCellView: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tickerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteImageView: UIImageView!{ didSet {
    let panGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                            action: #selector(gestureAction))
    favouriteImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var companyNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var deltaLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

@objc func gestureAction() {
    favouriteImageView.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

}

But nothing works.
If i change `favouriteImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)`
on `addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)`
Then, by clicking on the cell, the color will change.
But I want by clicking on the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYGGM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must check and change like below:

```
favouriteImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```